# Need direction (JSON related)

Tags: json

I want to show m.aliexpress.com search with filters, Example:

https://m.aliexpress.com/search.htm?keywords=flashlight#/

The filters (such as "free shipping" etc) are sending in post method and with JSON i think.

I'm not sure how should i find/do this request to get page with this filters.
I tried to find the address with HTTP Headers extension but not succeed much..
I need direction..

thanks!

Comment: found this address:
https://m.aliexpress.com/search/mainsearch/asy/GetMainSearchDataJson.do?keyword=flashlight&start=0&freeShipping=false&ignoreSPU=true&onePiece=false&pinProductIds=&pop=false&scene=&secondSort=&shipFromCity=&shipFromCountry=&shipFromProvince=&shipToCity=&shipToCountry=&shipToProvince=&categoryId=&attributes=&maxPrice=&minPrice=&spuId=&shoppingCoupon=&firstSort=MAIN&pageSize=20&isBigSale=false

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a JSON issue.  I believe it is an url encoding issue.  In the example you gave, "free shipping", html will stop after the word free and query for that.  You have to "encode" the space character in your url.  In the case of "free shipping", your url properly encoded would be:
https://m.aliexpress.com/search.htm?keywords=free%20shipping

There are many other characters other than "space" that must be encoded.  I'll leave it to your to research those html encoded characters.

Comment: Hey martin, i talked about filters at the bottom.

Comment: aren't your filters the key words you are using?

Comment: guess my confusion now is I checked your link.  I'm brought to a web page, not json.  I clicked the link in your comment.  No one has access to it.